# How can I generate Bitmap Pictures in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, bitmap

What's the best way to generate Pictures, Pixel by Pixel in Ruby on Rails. I have a two-dimenisonal matrix with all the color values for each pixel, which i want to vizualize.

Something like this:

```
myBitmap = new Bitmap(:width => Column.all.count, :height => Row.all.count)
Colum.all.each do |col|
 Row.all.each do |row|
  #Draw the Pixel, with the color information in the matrix
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this is really a RoR but more a Ruby question. One way is to use RMagick, a wrapper around ImageMagick. RMagick is said to leak memory and it can be a pain to install Rmagick/Imagemagick. I had best experiences when installing Imagemagick with brew (OS X).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rmagick'
width = 100
height = 100
data = Array.new(width) do
  Array.new(height) do
    [rand(255), rand(255), rand(255)]
  end
end


img = Magick::Image.new(width, height)

data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |item, column_index|
    #puts "setting #{row_index}/#{column_index} to #{item}"
    img.pixel_color(row_index, column_index, "rgb(#{item.join(', ')})")
  end
end

img.write('demo.bmp')
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post but think it's worth mentioning rmagick is still maintained: https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick

Answer (score 0):

You could also use GD2 and it's ruby binding. Does not seem to be very popular though.
Did not know about RMagick not beeing maintained anymore. Thanks.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gd2'

width = 100
height = 100
data = Array.new(width) do
  Array.new(height) do
    rand(16777216)
  end
end
image = GD2::Image::TrueColor.new(width, height)
data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |item, column_index|
    image.set_pixel(row_index, column_index, item)
  end
end

File.open('gd2demo.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << image.png
end
```